Problem mapping response to Model class [Elasticsearch.NET 8.13]
I am unable to map the ElasticsearchClient SearchASync result into my data model. Gotten a conversion error:

The server encountered an error processing the request. Please see the
[service help page] for constructing valid requests to the service.
The exception message is 'The JSON value could not be converted to
System.String. Path: $.body | LineNumber: 0 | BytePositionInLine: 224.

Below are my code snippets:
namespace Model
{
    public class ElasticsearchDocs
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string Url { get; set; }
        public string Body { get; set; }
    }
}


public async Task<ElasticsearchDocs> SearchDocumentsByContent()
{
    ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = true;
    ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;

    
    var settings = new ElasticsearchClientSettings(new Uri("https://localhost:9200"))
        .CertificateFingerprint("795b709a3a0f70ee69f12320a5d73c49c2465a5dfcf4e1c13a928cef4c6e6c2e")
        .Authentication(new BasicAuthentication("<USERNAME>", "<PASSWORD>"));


    var client = new ElasticsearchClient(settings);

    ElasticsearchDocs esDocs = new ElasticsearchDocs(); 

    var request = new SearchRequest("search-ocr-poc")
    {
        Query = new MatchAllQuery()
    };

    var response = await client.SearchAsync<ElasticsearchDocs>(request);

    if (response.IsValidResponse)
    {
        esDocs = response.Documents.FirstOrDefault();
    }
    return esDocs;
}

not sure if need to manually map the field to data model.
Do i need to reindex my index ?
I already have my index created during the Elasticsearch connector processor.

This is my output when i use the GET command
GET /search-ocr-poc/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match_all": {}
  }
}

Output:
{
  "took": 21,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 2,
    "successful": 2,
    "skipped": 0,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": {
      "value": 69,
      "relation": "eq"
    },
    "max_score": 1,
    "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "search-ocr-poc",
        "_id": "ae7be893-6ced-4b0c-9230-b6bc168dcddd",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": {
          "creation_time": "2023-12-26T13:55:14Z",
          "file_name": "",
          "editor_id": 1073741823,
          "type": "list_item",
          "title": "All Draft Documents", 
          "url": "/sites/COPS/Reports%20List/DispForm.aspx?ID=5&Source=/sites/COPS/Reports%20List/AllItems.aspx&ContentTypeId=0x01009EC04F25E7BD464D9978DF8AB3448A9D",
          "size": 0,
          "id": "ae7be893-6ced-4b0c-9230-b6bc168dcddd",
          "author_id": 1073741823,
          "_timestamp": "2023-12-26T13:55:14Z"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "search-ocr-poc",
        "_id": "d4e860fd-8688-442b-a4b1-756dedb29397",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": {
          "creation_time": "2023-12-26T13:56:16Z",
          "server_relative_url": "/sites/COPS/Documents",
          "parent_web_url": "/sites/COPS",
          "id": "d4e860fd-8688-442b-a4b1-756dedb29397",
          "type": "document_library",
          "title": "Documents",
          "_timestamp": "2024-04-15T08:10:57Z",
          "url": "/sites/COPS/Documents"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}

